# Chat system foreach dynamic

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

What I'm trying to do is a User -> Admin || Admin -> User) chat system. What I've come up with so far looks really messed up, I tried `JOIN` on the select via SQLfiddle and it didn't work out so good.

Hopefully someone has a better idea and knows how to solve this problem.

My live chat PHP code -> http://pastebin.com/6z9ajCMW

And for my database structure for the `live_chat` and `live_chat_admin` it's here -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae70ec/26

And to get a basic idea of what I'm trying to make.

[image]

Comment: Should it be arranged by id on either side ?

Comment: I wanna show a conversation between the correct id's, so user_id should receive only responses where the `receive` is the user_id. I'm trying to make it show by latest message/response @SulthanAllaudeen

Comment: I guess this is not ok, Unless you do ajax call for every submit you can't get the one which got i.e., latest message/response. So instead of re-inventing the wheel why not you use any plugin which already achieved your aim ?

Comment: This chat system does not require message refreshes. This is not a live chat, only a chat with history @SulthanAllaudeen

Comment: I have written answer for you. You shall check it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem with a bit of help from @Eddy Ella.

I first of deleted `live_chat_admin` and moved receiver to `live_chat` instead.
And then I used CASE WHEN for switching between id's from user to admin.

Result, exactly as I wanted it.

PHP: http://pastebin.com/GXJEK6u4

SQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7081b/5

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to create a unique id for each chat so it easier for you to retrive it. Tables will be similar to something like this. 
[image: Tables]

Everytime a user starts a new chat, a new row is inserted in chat_unique. This will prevent other users to join a chat.

However, your page will reload everytime someone sends a new message. The best way would be to use Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

You just need to align right and left accordingly to the admin and the user that you have in your form as i have like in the below code

i.e.,

```
echo '<div align="right">';
```

and ending with

```
echo '</div>';
```

Code :

```
<?php
echo '<div class="live_chat">';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
// admin chat
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM live_chat_admin WHERE receiver = :user_id");
$sth->bindValue(':user_id', '2', PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();

    foreach ($sth as $row) {
    // Test message #1
    echo '<div align="right">'; 
    echo '<div class="admin_date">'.date('M j <b\\r/> H:i', strtotime($row['message_date'])).'</div>';
    echo '<div class="admin_bubble">'.$row['message'].'</div>';
    echo '<br /><br />';
    echo '</div>';  
    }
$conn = NULL;

// user chat
#$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
#$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test;charset=utf8', root);
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM live_chat WHERE user_id = :user_id");
$sth->bindValue(':user_id', '2', PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();

    foreach ($sth as $row) {
    // Test message #1
    echo '<div class="user_date">'.date('M j <b\\r/> H:i', strtotime($row['message_date'])).'</div>';
    echo '<div class="user_bubble">'.$row['message'].'</div>';
    echo '<br /><br />';
    }
$conn = NULL;

echo '</div>';

?>
```

So your screen will be as you expected [image]